# Angular: Error - The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type

Tags: angular

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR in src/app/product/product.component.html(11,46): The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
src/app/product/product.component.html(11,46): The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
```

This is line 11 the error references:

```
<p><a (click)="addToBasket(product)" [routerLink]="[product/product.product_id]">Buy</a></p>
```

I have a feeling the problem is elsewhere but I'm not sure.  Can anyone suggest anything to resolve this?

Comment: please show the code of method "addToBasket"

Comment: My guess is it is missing single quotes in the uri. So it is considering the / as an arithmetic operator. Try [product + '/' + product.product_id]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of your routerLink is a product (obj) divided at a number (product.product_id). This value must be a string

Try this:

```
<p><a (click)="addToBasket(product)" [routerLink]="['product/' + product.product_id]">Buy</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your **[routerLink]="[product/product.product_id]"** syntax is wrong. you should correct it as following:

```
[routerLink]="['/product/' + String(product.product_id)]"
```

your route should start with a **/** and you should have a path like

```
{ path: product/:id, component: SomeComponent}
```

inside your app.routing.ts